# Appium Getting "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/usr/local/share/android-sdk/build-tools'

Tags: java, android, appium, appium-android

I have `MAC-Sierra 10.12.6 (16G1510)`

I have set `ANDROID_HOME` in my `~/.bash_profile` file as

`export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/share/android-sdk`

if I do `ls /usr/local/share/android-sdk`, I could see

`platform-tools` and `tools` folder but there is no `build-tools` folder

When I ran Appium script getting error as

```
[Appium] Creating new AndroidDriver (v1.37.0) session
[Appium] Capabilities:
[Appium]   app: /Users/swapnil.kotwal/Swapnil/Appium/VodQaAdvancedAppium/VodQA.apk
[Appium]   newCommandTimeout: 700000
[Appium]   platformVersion: 5.1
[Appium]   browserName: android
[Appium]   platformName: android
[Appium]   udid: TA93300WA1
[Appium]   deviceName: Moto G1
[Appium]   version: 
[Appium]   platform: MAC
[BaseDriver] The following capabilities were provided, but are not recognized by appium: version, platform.
[AndroidDriver] The desired capabilities should generally not include both an app and a browserName
[BaseDriver] Session created with session id: 4a58f920-75df-46f3-a300-e450a1598178
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Getting Java version
[AndroidDriver] Java version is: 1.8.0_152
[ADB] Checking whether adb is present
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Shutting down Android driver
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Called deleteSession but bootstrap wasn't active
[MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/usr/local/share/android-sdk/build-tools'
    at Error (native)
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 148 ms - 222
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to install

```
sdkmanager --list
```

then I installed `build-tools` using below command

```
sdkmanager "build-tools;19.1.0"
```